# Why do you have to type "git" into git bash for each command?

Tags: git, repository

```
git status
git add
git clone 
git push
git commit....
```

Why doesn't Git bash allow you to type git commands like:

```
status
add
clone
push
```

And then for all non git command type "nongit" or something

```
nongit cd
nongit ls...
```

or is this possible?

Comment: Because it's a bash after all and people (well, except you :p) expect it to work that way. Usually someone does not use a shell just for git but also for other stuff such as compiling his code and possibly running/debugging it.

Comment: It's not direct answer on your question. But to not wasting time for typing long commands you could use git aliases. Perhaps [this page](http://tjhunt.blogspot.ru/2012/08/automating-git.html) could be useful.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ: Or bash completion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is so internal git commands no not clash with existing shell commands.

In modern CLI tools like git functionality is often broken into subtools which are invoked with an internal command. These commands can then take specific arguments which unclutters the tool interface. `git status` means "invoke the `status` command of `git`".

Comment: This is also true for p4 (perforce), cvs and svn.  The only CLI VCS that I know of that does not use a single binary with sub commands is RCS (ci, co, rcs, rcsdiff, rcsmerge, and rlog) and that is more likely a historical artifact because it was created early on.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps git-sh is what you're looking for:
Check https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh or install the Package git-sh in Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question of "why", it still a good find.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try out GIT Prompt:

http://volnitsky.com/project/git-prompt/